# Simulating varying WWAN/mobile network conditions on AWS Device Farm

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, networking, aws-device-farm

I'm currently evaluating AWS Device Farm as a means of testing our mobile applications (iOS & Android), which stream music.

Is it possible to simulate poor mobile network conditions when testing apps on Device Farm - for example, high latency, limited throughput and packet loss?

If so, how is this achieved? I was not able to find anything in the documentation about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for the AWS device farm team.
Currently, this feature is not present in device farm.